# Hyper-Q in K20c is grouped in 8?

Tags: cuda

I have a Kepler K20c with 13 SMXs and I'm doing some bioinformatics research on it. To get a better understanding of the Hyper-Q, I downloaded this sample from Nvidia: [simpleHyperQ](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simplehyperq) but I got different result.

### Their result

[image]

### My result

[image]

The sample just launches two different kernels in each stream to show different in Fermi and Kepler. But my result looks like something between Kepler and Fermi! 
Looks so strange! Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Comment: what command line are you using to invoke the sample?  are you running on windows or linux?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I just used the makefile which is come with the sample and just called ./simpleHyperQ from my Bash.

Comment: @RobertCrovella by the way, my own code also have this kind of problem, looks like my machine can only have concurrency of 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael. The problem is caused by CUDA_DEVICE_MAX_CONNECTIONS, just set this variable to 32 using:

```
export CUDA_DEVICE_MAX_CONNECTIONS=32
```

That will fix this

Comment: Just for future reference, this is documented in appendix I of the programming guide (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html) as of the 5.5 release.